# Why does the occurrence times $T_i$ having a continuous law imply that the $w_i$s cannot occur simultaneously?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, markov-process, exponential-distribution

I am studying Markov processes with exponential wait times. The following is said:

> Assume there are $k$ point events, denoted $w_1, \dots, w_k$, that the waiting time for $w_i$ to occur is $T_i \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda_i) \ (i = 1, \dots, k)$, and that the $T_i$s are independent. Let $T = \min_{1 \le i \le k} T_i$ be the time to the first occurrence, and let $Z = i$ if $T = T_i$, i.e., if $w_i$ is the first event to occur.

The author then makes the following remark:

> Since the occurrence times $T_i$ have a continuous law, the $w_i$s cannot occur simultaneously. It will follow that Markov process jumps to new states are always separated by a positive interval of time.

Why does the occurrence times $T_i$ having a continuous law imply that the $w_i$s cannot occur simultaneously? Since this mentions that it is because of a continuous law, I get the impression that this has something to do with real analysis, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is a random variable with continuous law, then for any real number $y$, $P(X = y) = 0$.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with continuous laws, then $P(X = Y) = 0$. To prove this, you can use the joint distribution and Fubini-Tonelli:
\begin{align*}
P(X=Y) &= \iint_{\mathbb R^2}1_{\{x = y\}}\mathcal L_X(dx)\mathcal L_Y(dy)\\
&= \int_{\mathbb R}\bigg(\int_{\mathbb R} 1_{\{x = y\}}\mathcal L_X(dx)\bigg)\mathcal L_Y(dy) \\
&= \int_{\mathbb R}P(X = y)\mathcal L_Y(dy) = 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: Ohh, ok, yes, now I remember; this is just referring to the property of continuous random variables.